# Python request Json data, want to copy it back into csv file from excel

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-requests

This is the URL I'm trying to use python to pull back the json data from:

https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=y&type=8&season=2018&month=0&season1=2018&ind=0

This is the code (keep in mind I'm very new to learning Python):

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?'

params = dict(
    pos='all',
    stats='bat',
    lg='all',
    qual='y',
    type='8',
    season='2018',
    month='0',
    season1='2018',
    ind='0'
)

resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
data = resp.json()
print(data)
```

Am I setting this up right?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your response content is not in JSON notation, if you use print(resp.headers) you should see something like:

```
{
  'Cache-Control': 'private', 
  'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 
  'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0', 
  'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 
  'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 
  'Date': 'Thu, 07 Feb 2019 17:29:33 GMT', 
  'Content-Length': '313209'
}
```

As you can see the Content-Type is NOT JSON, so the decoder can't parse it.
You might need to use BeautifulSoup or some other scraping solution.